# QGIS sample data from LiDAR raster layer

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, lidar

I'm trying to pull data from the Scottish open data LiDAR information (https://remotesensingdata.gov.scot/data#/list) and I can use the Identify Features tool to click on a point and get the elevation as a "Gray_Index" attribute, but I can't find any way to sample this and assign the gray_index to a series of points on a separate layer.

[image]

I've been trying to use the "Sample Raster Values" tool which seems exactly what I need, but this keeps creating points with no information against them, since it seems the raster has no information in it's band.

[image]

Does anyone know a way to assign a series of points on a vector layer the corresponding GRAY_INDEX value based on their locations?

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to contain a question.